# Sybase to Teradata inquiry LIKE '[0-9]'

Tags: sql, regex, teradata, database-migration

```
CASE
         WHEN <in_data> LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' THEN SUBSTR(<in_data>,1,3)
ELSE '000'
END
```

We're doing a migration project from Sybase to Teradata, and having a problem figuring this one out :) I'm still new to Teradata.

I would like to ask the equivalent TD code for this - 
LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' to Teradata

Basically, it just checks whether the digits are numeric value.
Can someone give me a hint on this

Comment: Must be a 6 digit number. Does Teradata have regexp?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use REGEXP_SUBSTR to directly extract the three digits:

```
COALESCE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(in_data,'^[0-9]{3}(?=[0-9]{3}$)'), '000')
```

This looks for the first three digits and then does a lookahead for three following digits without adding them to the overall match.

`^` indicates the begin of the string, '$' the end, so there are no other characters before or after the six digits. `(?=...)` is a so-called "lookahead", i.e. those three digits are checked, but ignored.

If there's no match the regex returns `NULL` which is changed to '000'.

Comment: Thank you! yes this seems to be the efficient way. by the way, would like to ask, what does the ^, ?, and $ mean?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `regexp` instead of `like`, since `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` is a regular expression.

To do an exact match, you need to add anchors. ie, to match the string which contains an exact 6 digit chars.

```
regexp '^[0-9]{6}$'
```

or

```
regexp '^[[:digit:]]{6}$'
```